# Is there a way to export all request code in Paw app?

Tags: paw-app

I would like to be able to select multiple requests and export the code with the code generator of my choice-- something like a batch export. It appears that this is not possible in the current version of Paw, so I might have to script this up in AppleScript or something like that.

Am I correct that there is currently no way to generate code for multiple requests at once, and do you think I am on the right track in developing an AppleScript that repeats the GUI sequence to step down the request tree in the lefthand menu, export the code, and confirm the file location?

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to update this as I had the same question.

The answer is "sort of" but not as you expect. It is via clipboard.

- Open up preferences
- Choose the "Code Generation" tab
- Select your output type, i.e. cURL, API Blurprint, etc., and close Preferences
- In the sidebar select one or more requests you would like to export
- Copy them (Command+C, Edit > Copy, etc.)
- Paste where you need them

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.3.3 Paw allows you to export multiple requests at once:
https://luckymarmot.com/ru/paw/updates/2.3.3